# How to manually configure IP adress and default gateaway adress

Tags: windows-networking

So, I'm trying to configure hostednetwork, basically my laptop is connected to the internet through a CAT Ethernet cable, and I make a wlan hotspot, so I can connect to the internet through my phone. I configured it simular to [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-turn-your-windows-10-pc-wireless-hotspot). It works most of the time, sometimes I have to disconnect the cable, reconnect it, disable the network device and reenable it again, and then it works, however while playing with it. I changed something.

(This is the UI IPv4 Settings of the network device "Local Area Connection 13*" which is only enabled when you type `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`)
[image: Windows UI ipv4 properties]

There was a manual configuration ip, subnet mask, and default gateway written down, which worked before, but I changed it to "Obtain an IP adress automatically", as soon as I did this I started to get other kinds of errors. I don't remember the original IP adress, subnet mask and default gateway, but keep in mind that I do have connection to the internet through the laptop, but devices that connect to the Computer's wifi have issues.

On Android when (connected to my computer's wifi), I `ping 1.1.1.1` I find:
`From 192.168.137.191: icmp_seq=XX Destination Host Unreachable`

on Windows instead what I get when I do treaceroute is `1 Transmit error: code 1231`

So maybe I can do something about it if I configure the IP address manually again? How can I find out where the problem is?

Comment: I posted this on networking engineering but I was redirected here, but I had to wait 40 minutes, while waiting I figured it out, so I decided to just post the answer myself, but if someone can post it how to do this on command line, I can still upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

There might be many ways to solve this problem and this might not be the only problem that you have, but this is what you can try.
Actually a simple fix for this, basically you need to share your Internet again.
Go to Network connections and right-click the network device where you're sharing your internet
[image: ethernet]

Go to Properties, and then click on the Sharing tab

[image: sharing tab]

uncheck the Allow other users to connect through this network, click ok, go to the tab again, and share Local Area Network* 13 again.
Windows will have filled this information for you automatically.

[image: yay]